AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance, should cat /etc/hostname in fact be the (current) IP?
I'm looking at an EC2 instance and ...
# cat /etc/hostname
ip-172-31-69-69

and ...
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

1. Regarding the /etc/hostname ..
What the heck is "ip-172-31-69-69". That's not at all the elastic IP  one uses to find the server on the internet (ie the node/express server running on this instance).
Is that actually correct?
2. Regarding the /etc/hosts
Random googling suggested, with no explanation, that as well as
127.0.0.1 localhost

one can add
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ip-172-31-69-69

I tried this and it seems to make the server work more reliably. But I have no clue why, or if it's a good idea.
The combo of ip-172-31-69-69 as the hostname and having both lines in hosts, seems to work most reliably (I tried all permutations).
Is it ok/correct to have more than one line in /hosts ?

44.212.666.666 is a public IP. 172.31.69.69 is a private IP. The EC2 instance will only know about its private IP, since the public IP (Elastic IP) is provided via a NAT service outside of the EC2 instance.

Yeah it should probably be using localhost instead of anything else, but you haven't really provided any info about what your express app is doing with that DNS address, so I can't say for sure.

It's not super obvious that the value should be localhost. You never provided enough information in your question and comments for anyone to know for sure what that value should be.

Thanks @MarkB . the question got opened again, so, I drastically simplified it to the key points.  (Actually you already answered the first key point in your comments, thanks!)
